# Creating a custom color map for heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colormap

I have the following heatmap and I want to make a custom color map for it. For the color map I would like 0, 1, and -3 correspond to red, pink and blue, respectively, so that from 0 to 1 the red color gets lighter and from 0 to -3 the red color gradually turns to blue. I tried to find a solution among the questions that have already been asked in StackOverFlow but couldn't find anything close to my case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

test_data = {"a":{"a":1 , "b":0.5, "c":-0.2, "d":-2.7} , "b":{"a":0.2 , "b":0, "c":-1.3, "d":-2}, "c":{"a":0 , "b":1, "c":-2.2, "d":-0.005}, "d":{"a":-3 , "b":0.9, "c":0.01, "d":-1.15}}
test_data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,9))
_ = sns.heatmap(test_data_df, annot=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `LinearSegmentedColormap` from a dictionary (see [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/custom_cmap.html#custom-colormaps)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

test_data = {"a":{"a":1 , "b":0.5, "c":-0.2, "d":-2.7} , "b":{"a":0.2 , "b":0, "c":-1.3, "d":-2}, "c":{"a":0 , "b":1, "c":-2.2, "d":-0.005}, "d":{"a":-3 , "b":0.9, "c":0.01, "d":-1.15}}
test_data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,9))
cdict = {
    'red': (
        (0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
        (0.75,  1.0, 1.0),
        (1.0,  1.0, 1.0),
    ),
    'green': (
        (0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
        (1.0,  0.0, 0.0),
    ),
    'blue': (
        (0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
        (0.75,  0.0, 0.0),
        (1.0,  0.8, 0.8),
    )
}
blue_red_pink = LinearSegmentedColormap('', cdict)
_ = sns.heatmap(test_data_df, annot=True, cmap=blue_red_pink)
```

Here your interval would be -3..1 so in relative term, -3 is at position 0 and 0 at position 0.75...

Output:
[image]