# How to increase the resolution of colormap in seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I have the following heatmap:

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="crest_r")
```

[image]

I want to be able to see the differences between 0 and 0.1. Specifically if they are higher than 0.05. Is there anyway to change the cmap to a higher "resolution"? If not do you have any suggestions as to how I can differentiate p<0.05 and p>0.05.

Comment: You could create a custom color map with a color gradient of your liking around 0.05. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74879016/13525512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want.

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="crest_r", vmin=0, vmax=0.1)
```

Comment: This works thanks! Do you know how to show the values only of those lower than 0.05?

Comment: @caterina If I understand you correctly: `sns.heatmap(df, cmap="crest_r", vmin=0, vmax=0.05)`

Comment: I meant as annotations. Only show the values lower than 0.05.

Comment: Oh no. I do not know a solution for this!